# MySQL Where In with Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been knocking my head against a brick wall with this query for hours and thought I'd chance my luck here.

I'm working on a query which returns Products based on Categories and Category Ratings.

A simplified schema would look like:

**products**
id
name
price

**categories**
id
name

**products_categories**
product_id
category_id
rating ( 0 - 5 )

The query I currently have is as follows:

```
SELECT 
`products` . *, products_categories.*
FROM
`products`
    JOIN
`products_categories` ON (`products`.`id` = `products_categories`.`product_id`)
WHERE
`products_categories`.`category_id` IN ('5' , '24', '41')
    AND `products_categories`.`rating` > 1
    AND `products`.`enabled` = 1
HAVING count(distinct (products_categories.category_id)) = 3
ORDER BY `amount` ASC
LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0
```

The first part of the query is to select all Products which belong to those 3 categories which works fine, however, the part I'm struggling with is the rating part.

I need the query to select all of the Products which belong to those 3 categories IF the categories have a rating of 1 or greater. As it stands, the query only operates on the rating of the last category which returns bogus results.

Any input would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just a point in the right direction.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause so that `COUNT()` will count by product, rather than counting everything at once.

```
SELECT 
`products` . *, products_categories.*
FROM
`products`
    JOIN
`products_categories` ON (`products`.`id` = `products_categories`.`product_id`)
WHERE
`products_categories`.`category_id` IN ('5' , '24', '41')
    AND `products_categories`.`rating` > 1
    AND `products`.`enabled` = 1
GROUP BY products.id
HAVING count(distinct (products_categories.category_id)) = 3
ORDER BY `amount` ASC
LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that out - feel like such a ditz. Thanks a bunch Barmar! I'll accept this answer when it lets me. Thanks again.

Comment: It makes my brain hurt that MySQL will allow you to run this query without the group by.

Comment: Yes, I too cannot believe MySQL let's you operate on aggregate functions without actually specifying a `GROUP BY`

Comment: It's allowed because sometimes you want to operate on the whole result set, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE rating = 3`.

Comment: since product_id appears to be a foreign key to the products table - and you're grouping at the level of the product.id, it doesn't make any sense to have products_categories.* in the select clause - in the absence of an explicit grouping it will return an unpredicatble row from that table.

Comment: @symcbean It doesn't look like he cares about the other columns in that table, since he's combining the rows with `GROUP_CONCAT`. I suspect the `SELECT` clause is just an example for SO.